# Ada: Flatten Record to Byte array

Tags: ada

I have a record made of smaller types, a total of 16 bits in size.

```
type Type_1 is (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8);
for Type_1 use (val1 => 0, val2 = 1, val3 = 2, val4 => 3
                 val5 => 4, val6 => 5, val7 => 6, val8 => 7);
for Type_1'Size use 3;

type Type_2 is (val1, val2);
for Type_2 use (val1 => 0, val2 = 1);
for Type_2'Size use 1;

etc, etc

type The_Record is record
    element_1 : Type_1;
    element_2 : Type_2;
    element_3 : Type_3;
    element_4 : Type_4;
end record;
for the_Record use record
    element_1 at 0 range 0 .. 2;
    element_2 at 0 range 3 .. 4;
    element_3 at 0 range 5 .. 12;
    element_4 at 0 range 13 .. 15;
end record;
for The_Record'Size use 16;
```

How can I flatten 'The_Record' into an array of bytes or something similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you say *why* you need an array of bytes? since clearly `The_Record` is in a sense already a (2-element) array of bytes.

Comment: I suspect he's trying for some form of serialization

Comment: Some standards insist that the "data" section of a message (serialisation of data) be represented as a byte array... some implementations will therefore mimic this to placate [ISVV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_software_verification_and_validation) monkeys.

Comment: NWS, if there's no endianness or other representation problem it's often just as easy to import the send & receive functions with the desired data type. Another way to overlay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `Unchecked_conversion`, however, this approach is *unchecked* and you are therefore telling the compiler (a) that you know what you're doing, and (b) that it cannot help you [otherwise it would be named checked_conversion].

Another way that you can do the conversion is with overlaying, this is **my** preferred approach (if it is not a simple type-renaming issue) as if things change then the conversion-function can be modified as needed.

```
-- Subtype-renaming.
Subtype Byte is Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
-- General type for conversion to a collection of bytes.
Type Byte_Array is Array (Positive Range <>) of Byte;
-- Speciffic collection of bytes from The_Record.
Subtype Record_Bytes is Byte_Array(1..The_Record'Size/Byte'Size);

-- Converting record to bytes...
Function Convert( Input : The_Record ) return Record_Bytes is
    Result : Constant Record_Bytes;
    For Result'Address use Input'Address;
    Pragma Import( Convention => Ada, Entity => Result );
begin
    Return Result;
end Convert;

-- Converting bytes to record... in Ada 2012!
Function Convert( Input : Record_Bytes ) return The_Record is
    Result : The_Record with
            Import, Convention => Ada, Address => Input'Address;
begin
    Return Result;
end Convert;
```

---

Another, and probably better, way (if you are trying for serialization. as I suspect) of doing this would be to create read/write functions and override the default `'read` and `'write` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

This in an example of how to use the `Unchecked Conversion` way:

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Uc is 

   type The_Record is record
      A : Integer;
      B : Integer;
   end record;

   -- define a byte sized thing...
   type U8 is mod 2**8;
   for U8'Size use 8;

   -- have your array defined according to
   -- the size of the record it needs to hold
   type U8_Record_Array is array (1 .. The_Record'Size / U8'Size) of U8;

   -- instantiate Unchecked_Conversion
   function To_Array is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => The_Record,
                                                      Target => U8_Record_Array);
   -- Declare a record and convert it to an array
   R : constant The_Record := (A => 1, B => 2);
   A : constant U8_Record_Array := To_Array (R);

begin
   -- Print the Array As Bytes
   for I in A'Range loop
      Ada.Text_Io.Put (U8'Image (A(I)));
   end loop;

end Uc;
```

Depending on *Exactly* what you are intending to do, Both the Overlay & `Unchecked Conversion` ways will have pros & cons associated with them :)

Comment: You need to round up when calculating the length of `U8_Record_Array` - `1 .. (The_Record'Size + U8'Size - 1) / U8'Size`.